# you tube API not working ios

Tags: ios, api, youtube

We are using the google API to play you tube videos but we are unable to load the videos suddenly from today.  Reference Link : http://www.youtube.com/v/1KkDNkxPcJc?version=3&f=favorite&app=youtube_gdata   Till 2 days back i was able to play this video but suddenly stopped working on iOS UIWebView. Is there any reason ? what should i do now.  Please help me on the same to continue using google API.  Approach followed from : Method 2 from following link.  http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html   It would be greattful if you help me earliest.  Thank you. Girish Patil

Comment: The above case is observed in ios 5.1 and on ios 7 its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use this code with your video link ..

```
self.videoString=@" http://www.youtube.com/v/1KkDNkxPcJc?version=3&f=favorite&app=youtube_gdata";

NSString* queryString=[self.videoString lastPathComponent];

NSArray* queryArray = [queryString componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];

self.urlIDForALLString=[queryArray objectAtIndex:0];


NSString*withMString=[@"http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=" stringByAppendingString:self.urlIDForALLString];


NSString*autoPlay=[withMString stringByAppendingString:@"&autoplay=1" ];

[webViewDwn loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:autoPlay]]];

NSString *subString = [self.videoString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0, [self.videoString rangeOfString: @"?"].location)];
                NSLog(@"....%@",subString);

[self embedYouTube:subString frame:self.VideoWebView.frame];
```